# Thermal diffusion length- heat transfer

Tags: heat-conduction

what is the difference between thermal diffusivity and thermal diffusion length?since diffusivity itself means the extent of heat penetration into the volume of material?

Comment: Have you looked the terms up?

Comment: The extent of heat penetration into the volume of the material is a function of the diffusivity and time.